# Return most recent data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table, which is structured like this:

```
CREATE table match (ID1 int, ID2 int, CreatedDate, ConnectDisconnect)
```

I am trying to write an SQL statement that will return the most recent rematch record grouped by id1 and id2.  For example, please see the data below:

```
1,2,'2014-06-05', C
1,3,'2014-06-05', C
1,4,'2014-06-05', C
N1,N2,'2014-06-05',D
```

Please see the SQL statement below:

```
select max(CreatedDate), ID1,ID2 FROM match
group by ID1,ID2
```

This will show the most recent decision that was made on ID1 and ID2.  The problem is that the matching records can be either way around.  For example:

```
1,2,'2014-06-04', C
2,1,'2014-06-05', D
```

The data above shows that records 1 and 2 were connected on 04/06/2014 and disconnected on 05/06/2014.  My query above will return two rows, however I only want it to return one row i.e. the most recent (the data dated 05/06/14 in the case above).

Comment: Well, if you only have a date column (not date-time) then how are you going to know which row is more recent?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, using `case` and `row_number()`:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when id1 < id2 then id1 else id2 end),
                                             (case when id1 < id2 then id2 else id1 end)
                                order by CreatedDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from match m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry for ther delay reviewing this.  The IDs are not always integers e.g. N1, N2 etc.  Therefore I do not believe this will work.  I have updated the question.  Do you agree?

Comment: (1) The question *clearly* specifies that the `id`s are integers.  (2) it doesn't matter, so long as `<` is defined for the type (and it is defined for SQL base types).

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but this may do what you want (not sure what the syntax of concatenation is in SQL Server):

```
select max(CreatedDate), case when ID1 < ID2 concat(ID1,',',ID2) else concat(ID2,',',ID1) end as combinedIds
FROM match
group by case when ID1 < ID2 concat(ID1,',',ID2) else concat(ID2,',',ID1) end
```